# SSRS report email subscription should not be sent, when there is no data in the report

Tags: reporting-services

SSRS report email subscription should not be sent, when there is no data in the report.

Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

This report doesn't have any parameters. I am using 2016 reporting server.

Comment: are you using  SQL SERVER standard or SQL SERVER Enterprise? You usually use a data driven subscription to get around issues like this.. but unfortunately, only available on the Enterprise version

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a data-driven subscription. If the query for the instructions for the data-drive subscription does not return a row, no report will be sent. Just base the SQL statement for the data-driven subscription off of the same data from your report.

[Link for Ref](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/data-driven-subscription-in-ssrs-2008-r2.html)

[Link 2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6382/sql-server-reporting-services-empty-report-from-a-data-driven-subscription/)

Comment: thank you for the response, I see an error when I click on the link. Can provide me steps to create the data driven subscription and how it works?

Comment: The report I am using doesn't have any parameters, does the data driven subscriptions work only when there are parameters in the report?

Comment: I got the answer, your link is much helpful, thank you

Comment: great, could you please up vote and mark it as solved. It will help others as well.